# Return literal JSON strings in spring mvc @ResponseBody

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I am storing objects in my database as JSON strings. I want to make a REST service that exposes these strings. When I write my methods however, the strings I get back have their quotes escaped. For example, I have included a method that returns a String,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getTest() {
    return "{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"foo\"}";
}
```

but when I call this method in the browser I get a back "{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"foo\"}" when what I really want to happen is {"a": 1, "b": "foo"}. I think "String" as the return type is likely the problem, but what else can I do? A wrapper class does the same thing:

```
{
  "value" : "{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"foo\"}"
}
```

I could serialize it and then return the object, but that seems a bit ridiculous.
Here is a possibly the relevant portion of my configuration file:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
}

@Bean
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(true);
    return mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: as was suggested below, it seems the string is being double encoded. Commenting out the 2 classes in my configuration fixes this issue. However, I still have other places where I want to return Objects and would like to keep those running through that common serializing bean that I know where to configure. So I see my options as:
a) Do all the serializing myself. All methods return Strings, and those that are already JSON return themselves, and those that are objects all return JSONUtil.toJson(object). I don't love this approach, but I know it will work.
b) Use a wrapper class that looks kind of like:

```
public static class Wrapper {

    @JsonRawValue
    private final String value;
}
```

This leads to an awkward "value" at the front though that has no real meaning.

Basically what I want is @JsonRawValue, but to have it work on RequestMapping methods instead of properties.
Thoughts? Opinions? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 49):

This works with Jackson 2 (at least):

```
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @RequestMapping(..)
    public @ResponseBody Json get() {
        return new Json("{ \"attr\" : \"value\" }");
    }
}

class Json {

    private final String value;

    public Json(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    @JsonRawValue
    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Not particularly pretty but works. I only wish Spring supported this:

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public @JsonRawValue @ResponseBody String get() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great help. Did anything changed in the last 3 years?

Comment: @Kulpemovitz Not that I know of

Comment: Thanks. This is the only solution that worked for me. Can use this class if have springfox library: springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json

Answer (score 29):

I guess what you want is producing a response with content-type `application/json`. In your case, when you have the json-data as a raw string, do the following:

In your controller add `produces="application/json"` to your `@RequestMapping` attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody
String getTest() {
    return "{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"foo\"}";
}
```

Then you have to configure the `StringHttpMessageConverter` to accept the application/json media-type.

With Java-config:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList( //
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, //
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML, //
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    converters.add(stringConverter);
}
```

With XML-config:

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This question should be marked as a proper solution :-) thanks

Answer (score 11):

I used this:

```
@RequestMapping(..)
@ResponseBody
public JsonNode myGetRequest(){
...
//rawJsonString is the raw Json that we want to proxy back to the client
return objectMapper.readTree(rawJsonString);
}
```

And the Jackson converter knew how to transform the JsonNode into plain Json.

Comment: looks like you parse rawJsonString and then return object that will converted to json again. not a pretty solution...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me to avoid returning JsonObject with escape characters!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to convert JSON String to JSON object in your browser, keep string convertor before Jackson convertor.
Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289981/jackson-converter-and-javax-validation-annotation-not-working-together/37388093#37388093) for complete example. It works with custom converter configuration plus spring validation.

### It Works

```
converters.add(stringConverter());
converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
```

### It Doesn't

```
converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
converters.add(stringConverter());
super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
```

Comment: That was the issue for me. Changing the order of the insertion to the list solved the problem. +1

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I wanted the response type to be determined by a request parameter, so had to specify the content type in the code, e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping("/myurl")
public void radiusSearch(@RequestParam responseType, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String jsonResponse = makeSomeJson();
    response.setContentType(responseType);
    try {
        response.getOutputStream().write(jsonResponse.getBytes());
    } finally {
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Today we had the same issue and solved it with multiple converters. Now every `String` will treated as a string and every other `Object` will get serialised by Jackson. This allows to serialise manually (by returning `String`) or automatically (by returning something else) in Spring controllers.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(stringConverter());
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}

@Bean
public StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter() {
    final StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(UTF_8);
    stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN,
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return stringConverter;
}

@Bean
public GenericHttpMessageConverter<Object> mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = objectMapperBuilder().build();
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    return converter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\"` means the character `"` is being escaped, which is standard. If it's being printed like that, you're probably double-serializing the object.

Comment: yeah, double serializing would account for it. But where?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was just dealing with the opposite problem myself (I was returning a String and WANTED it to get converted to JSON).  In your case, it sounds like you simply want to have your String treated as a plain string and not have any sort of JSON conversion done on it as you already have JSON.

So in your case you don't want to use the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` (or the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` if you're now using Jackson2).  You want no conversions done at all, and that converter converts Java objects to/from JSON.  So instead you should just use the plain `StringHttpMessageConverter`.  You can do that by changing your setup method like this:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
}
```

This converter is applicable to `*/*` types (the document is incorrect which says `text/*`, I found out the hard way in the debugger).  So whether your content type is `application/json` or not, either way Spring won't mess with your Strings if you use this converter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is, this works perfectly without changing any configurations

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader;

JsonNode getTest() {
    return JsonLoader.fromString("{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"foo\"}");
}
```