# How to pass JSON object from ajax to controller in spring mvc?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

I am using spring mvc. I need to pass a json object from my jsp page to controller.

My ajax code:

```js
function createJSON() {
    jsonObj = [];
    item = {};
    $(".values").each(function() {

        var code = $(this).attr('id');
        item[code] = $('#' + code).val();
    });

    var content=JSON.stringify(item)


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "/pms/season/submit", 
        data: content,
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data) {  
            alert(response);   
        },  
        error : function(e) {  
            alert('Error: ' + e);   
        }  
    });                                                         
}
```

My controller code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveNewUsers( @RequestParam ("json") String json) {
    System.out.println( "json  ::::"+json );
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: When you say it is not working -- what is it doing? You can improve your question if you describe how it is going wrong

Answer (score 3):

@RequestParam("json") means that you are intending to include a request parameter called json in the URI, i.e. /submit?json=...

I think you intend to get the request body, i.e. @RequestBody.

I would then suggest that, unless you *really* need the raw JSON string, you would have the @RequestBody translated to a Java object for you:

```java
public void saveNewUsers(@RequestBody MyDto myDto) {
...
}
```

where MyDto would have getters/setters and fields matching the JSON class.

You can over omit the @RequestBody annotation if you annotate the controller with @RestController, instead of @Controller.

If you definitely want the raw JSON string, then take a look at this previous question: [Return literal JSON strings in spring mvc @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507064/return-literal-json-strings-in-spring-mvc-responsebody)